# Advanced tokenizer for a complex math expression

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I would like to tokenize a string that consists of integers,floats, operators, functions, variables and parentheses. The following example should brighten the essence of problem:

Current state:

```
String infix = 4*x+5.2024*(Log(x,y)^z)-300.12
```

Desired state:

```
 String tokBuf[0]=4 
 String tokBuf[1]=* 
 String tokBuf[2]=x 
 String tokBuf[3]=+ 
 String tokBuf[4]=5.2024 
 String tokBuf[5]=* 
 String tokBuf[6]=( 
 String tokBuf[7]=Log
 String tokBuf[8]=( 
 String tokBuf[9]=x
 String tokBuf[10]=, 
 String tokBuf[11]=y 
 String tokBuf[12]=) 
 String tokBuf[13]=^ 
 String tokBuf[14]=z 
 String tokBuf[15]=) 
 String tokBuf[16]=- 
 String tokBuf[17]=300.12
```

All tips and solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use something like [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) to define the grammar of your expression and generate a parser for it.

Comment: yacc is another good tool.  Most likely you want a graph of symbols rather than an array.

Comment: If you are building an expression evaluator, try GNU libmatheval or muParse before :)

Comment: Scala has built in support for [Combinator Parsers](http://henkelmann.eu/2011/01/13/an_introduction_to_scala_parser_combinators) which you can use. Chapter 33 of [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) has a example parsing a mathematical expression using them. You can use Scala compiled classes directly from Java.

Comment: If you, as I, are not to use language utilities I can share with you my expression parser.

Comment: @PeterLawrey for tokenizing, the right one of the lex/yacc pair would actually be lex. Not sure how any of them would be supposed to help with java (other than reading how it works) though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Java stream tokenizer. The interface is a bit strange but one gets used to it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Example code that parses to the requested String list (you probably want to use the tokenizer directly or at least use an Object list so you can store numbers directly as Double):

```
public static List<String> tokenize(String s) throws IOException {
  StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
  tokenizer.ordinaryChar('-');  // Don't parse minus as part of numbers.
  tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/');  // Don't treat slash as a comment start.
  List<String> tokBuf = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    switch(tokenizer.ttype) {
      case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
        tokBuf.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
        break;
      case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
        tokBuf.add(tokenizer.sval);
        break;
      default:  // operator
        tokBuf.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
    }
  }
  return tokBuf; 
}
```

Test run:

```
System.out.println(tokenize("4*x+5.2024*(Log(x,y)^z)-300.12"));
[4.0, *, x, +, 5.2024, *, (, Log, (, x, ,, y, ), ^, z, ), -, 300.12]
```

Comment: p.s. You might be interested in my expression parser on github: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/expressionparser

Comment: You would want to add tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/') as '/' is treated as EOF and the loop will terminate prematurely if there is a slash operator.

Comment: Done. Does recognizing C++ comments turn this off? Might be safest to use reset() instead and then to set everything explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools
Example of algorithm:
*step#1*: read '4' => numeric token => read chars until reach non-num symbol(that is ' * '). The first just read, tokBuf[0] is a numeric token.
*step#2*: read '*' => token represents a binary operator.
*step#3*: read 'x'. Perhaps, ot a function symbol => mark the next token as var-token.
And so on.
The next step is evaluation, I guess? Reverse Polish notation or syntax trees will help...